# Zend: How to append unique <style> tags in sub-pages <head> tag

Tags: php, optimization, zend-framework, zend-view

I have a really big website to work on, which a lot of the sub-pages have unique CSS styles written inline.

Each page is structured in a way that it uses different `.phtml` parts to create one html page - the style used in a specific part is called from within the `.phtml` file, and results a page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="someStyle">
        ...
    </div>

    <style type="text/css">
        .someStyle{
            color:red;
        }
        .someOtherStyle{
            background: blue;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="someOtherStyle">
        ...
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Is there a decent way to append this `<style>` tag, even as string, to the `<head>` tag of a page although written within the page? (as a function maybe?)

Following Zend documentation: 
https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.head-style.html

it seems like there is a solution for linking `.css` files, and not short `<style>` tags.

- I don't want to create a file and link it to the `<head>` tag.
- I want it as a short `<style>` tag as it is.

**Wanted result:** https://jsfiddle.net/k0c8cssj/

(I couldn't paste it here something doesn't work right with the code tags.)

Edit: Ok there it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .someStyle{ color:red; }
    .someOtherStyle{ background: blue;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="someStyle">
        ...
    </div>

    ~ in the .phtml view file - the CSS function/string/command is there 

    <div class="someOtherStyle">
        ...
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Using something like this:

```
    $styles = '.testingClass{color:red;}';
    $this->view->headStyle()->appendStyle($styles);
```

works only from within a controller and not from a view.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the headStyle viewhelper in your partials:

```
<?php $this->headStyle()->captureStart() ?>
.someStyle{
    color:red;
}
.someOtherStyle{
    background: blue;
}
<?php $this->headStyle()->captureEnd() ?>
```

https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-view/helpers/head-style/#capturing-style-declarations

And add `<?= $this->headStyle() ?>` to your layout's head tag.

I recommend using .css files to **reduce duplicate code**, you can either append or prepend your .css files in the partials:

```
// place at a particular offset:
$this->headStyle()->offsetSetStyle(100, $this->basePath('css/style.css'));

// place at end:
$this->headStyle()->appendStyle('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

// place at beginning:
$this->headStyle()->prependStyle($this->basePath('css/style.css'));
```

Also from the docs.